# transmission-remote commands are erroring with Unexpected response: <h1>401: Unauthorized</h1>Unauthorized User: deflate, gzip

Tags: linux, bittorrent, transmission

I'm running the latest Raspbian distribution and just installed the `transmission` packages.

I've been unable to set it up properly because whenever I run a `transmission-remote` command - say, to alter some base configurations - I keep getting the same error:

```
$ transmission-remote -DU -c required -p 9091 -w ~/torrents
Unexpected response: <h1>401: Unauthorized</h1>Unauthorized User: deflate, gzip
```

I can't find any good docs or tutorials out there to troubleshoot with, and I suspect I missed out on a step in the initial setup process which has resulted in this error. I'll already tried setting a username/password, i.e.

```
$ transmission-remote --auth myusername:mypassword
```

which succeeded, but it's still throwing the same "Unexpected response" error for all other commands.

Does anyone have an idea of why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

I can do it passing the user/password with flag -n

pi@raspbmc:~/torrent$ transmission-remote -a prueba.torrent
Unexpected response:

## 401: Unauthorized

Unauthorized User: deflate, gzip

pi@raspbmc:~/torrent$ transmission-remote -a -n user:password prueba.torrent
localhost:9091/transmission/rpc/ responded: "success"